# ngCookies do not load

Tags: angularjs

I have the following problem.

Here's my angular app defenition:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.utils',
    'ngCookies',
    'oc.lazyLoad'
]);
```

Here's part of my main html file:

```
<!-- ANGULAR -->
<script src="assets/plugins/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/angular-ui-util/ui-utils.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/angular-oc-lazyload/ocLazyLoad.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--ngCookies-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So I supposed I've done all I need to do to use `$cookieStore`. And yet, when I run my app, I see a blank browser window, and in console:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCookies due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCookies' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=ngCookies
minErr/<@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:63:12
module/<@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:1774:1
ensure@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:1698:38
module@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:1772:1
loadModules/<@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:4115:22
forEach@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:323:11
loadModules@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angular/angular.js:4099:5
loadModules/<@file:///D:/Webstorm/Magic/assets/plugins/angu
```

Can anyone tell me what did I forget to do?

Comment: things you could try:
1. Add http:// to the src
2. Try downloading with bower then add it like the rests.

Comment: @BabajideFowotade thanks, I downloaded it and added to the folder, where angular.js is, and it now works, -ish. You can post it as an answer, and I will accept it :)

Comment: Okay i have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you could try:

1. Add http:// to the src
2. Try downloading with bower then add it like the rests